# How can I add generated kotlin sources to source path in gradle?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, openapi-generator

For generated java sources I use:

```
sourceSets["main"].java {
    srcDir("$buildDir/generated/java")
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile::class) {
    dependsOn("myGenerator")
}
```

But now I have generated kotlin sources and function sourceSets["main"].kotlin is not defined.

Comment: It is working:    

    sourceSets["main"].withConvention(conventionType = KotlinSourceSet::class) {
        kotlin.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/kotlin")
    }

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: Since you answered your question yourself, please take the time to add this as a real answer and approve it.

Comment: Please vote on feature request to make this smoother: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45161

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```kotlin
sourceSets["main"].withConvention(conventionType = KotlinSourceSet::class) {
    kotlin.srcDir("$buildDir/generated/kotlin")
}
```

More: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: `withConvention` is deprecated, I'm writing this in Gradle plugins personally.
```
sourceSets.named("main").configure {
            this.extensions.getByName<SourceDirectorySet>("kotlin").srcDirs("src")
        }
```